# Parameter correspondence: callback vs. closures (?)

Tags: javascript, parameters, callback, nested, closures

With javascript closures and callbacks, I am confused on the difference between why the parameters that a named, nested function take are different (inherited from the outer function?) than a closure's parameters. For example:

```
var filter = function (collection, test) {
    var newArray = [];
    each(collection, function (value) {
        if (test(value)) { 
            newArray.push(value);
        }
    });
    return newArray;
};
```

The filter function operates on the each function. What input does the "value" parameter (in each) correspond to? Does a callback function's parameter automatically line up with filter's first parameter because they are both the first parameter of their respective functions? If the outer function and the inner one both accepted another parameter, would those line up because of their position as well? The parameter relationship between  the inner/outer function here seems to be different from a closure's parameter (the closure seems to accept a new parameter; its parameters don't line up with the outer one's parameters) For example:

```
var outer = function(par1, par2) {
    var hold = par1 + par2;

    function inner(par3) {
       return par3 + par1 + par2;
    }
    return inner;
};

var closure = outer (5,4);

closure(2);
```

I see that the inner function is returned from the outer function (when stored in another variable) and takes its own parameter separate from the outer function.

Do named/established functions inherit their parameter correspondence from their enclosing functions?

Do callback functions take on their own parameter - separate from their enclosing function - because they are returned out of that function and saved to a variable?

Answer (score 1):

> What input does the "value" parameter (in each) correspond to?

That depends on what `each` does. It isn't a standard JS global and you haven't shared your definition of it.

> Does a callback function's parameter automatically line up with filter's first parameter because they are both the first parameter of their respective functions?

No. The arguments pass to any function are dependant on the code that calls that function.

> If the outer function and the inner one both accepted another parameter, would those line up because of their position as well?

No.

> Do named/established functions inherit their parameter correspondence from their enclosing functions?

No.

> Do callback functions take on their own parameter - separate from their enclosing function

Yes

> because they are returned out of that function and saved to a variable?

No. It is because they are functions.

```js
function outer(foo, bar) {
  console.log("Outer gets foo " + foo + " because foo is a argument of outer");

  console.log("Outer gets bar " + bar + " because foo is a argument of outer");

  return inner;


  function inner(baz) {
    console.log("Inner gets foo " + foo + " because foo is a variable still in scope");
    console.log("Inner gets bar " + bar + " because bar is a variable still in scope");
    console.log("Inner gets baz " + baz + " because baz is an argument of inner");
  }

}

var returned_inner = outer(1, 2);
returned_inner(3);
```

---

> With javascript closures and callbacks, I am confused on the difference between why the parameters that a named, nested function take are different (inherited from the outer function?) than a closure's parameters.

Your confusion problem springs from the simple fact that, most of the time, when you are using a callback, the function that actually calls it is *written by someone else* and *you never look at it*.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can sum up the answer to all of the questions by saying that there is absolutely no requirement at all for the parameters of an inner function to have anything at all to do with the parameters of the enclosing function.

They are completely unrelated values.

For example:

```
function f(a, b, c, d, e) {
    // You mentioned "named, nested" function in your question...
    return function unusedName(x) {return x}
}
console.log(f(1, 2, 3, "four", 25/5)(100));
```

will display 100.

Of course, in reality, you would *want* the inner function to somehow or other use the parameters of the outer function, otherwise the parameters to the outer function are useless.

But there is no requirement that they "line up." How you create your closure, that is how your returned inner function decides to use the values from the environment provided by the outer function, is wholly up to you. The language itself enforces nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Please consider changing most of the hypotheses in the question :-)

### Identifier scope.

When javascript code uses an unadorned identifier (such as a variable name, the name of an object or the name of a function) inside a function, the javascript engine looks to see if the identifier is the name of a local variable, the name of a nested function defined within the same function body, or the name of a formal parameter. If not found it will search for the identifier, in the same manner, in a next most outer function (if a function searched is nested), or look for the identifier in global scope if the last function searched was itself global.

Hence there is no "lining up" of nested function parameters, there is just searching the scope chain. Outer function parameters, variables and named function definitions are all in scope of inner functions. There is no automatic "relationship" between formal parameter definitions in different functions unless  planned by the programmer.

### Closures

Be careful about categorizing functions as call backs *or* closures. Often a call back function forms a closure. In summary, a closure is caused by keeping a reference to a nested function after its outer function has returned. This can result from storing a reference to the inner function either before or after the outer function returns, or by passing a reference to the inner function to some other function for use as an asynchronous call back. A long as reference to the inner function is being held somewhere, any values it references within its scope chain cannot be made available for garbage collection because they are accessible.

### forEach

The `each` function appears to be an iterator function being applied to the collection passed as an argument. Javascript supports a standardized `forEach` to iterated over Array, Map and Set objects. Please refer to [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) for further details on how it is called and calls back call back function.